# Combine `map` and `use` expl3 macros

Tags: macros, expl3, comma-separated-list, mapping, seq

I'm trying to build a macro
that processes a comma-separated-list of elements
so that:

```
\MapAndUse{a,b,c}
```

would produce:

[image: expected]

My first intuition is to use a [`expl3`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/l3kernel/expl3.pdf) combination
of `\seq_map*` to process each element in turn
(here, wrap into parentheses)
then `\seq_use*` to organize them around `--` markers.

But this does not work as expected:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\MapAndUse}{ m }{%
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_raw_seq {#1}
    \seq_map_variable:NNn \l_raw_seq \i {(\i)}
    % \seq_show:N \l_raw_seq
    \seq_use:Nn \l_raw_seq {\ --\ }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\MapAndUse{a,b,c}

\end{document}
```

Since it produces:

[image: unexpected]

From what I understand:

- from the [doc](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/l3kernel/expl3.pdf): `\seq_map_*` macros directly expand to the input stream.
- from `\seq_show:N \l_raw_seq`: the sequence is not actually affected by the`\seq_map` command (elements are not parenthesized)

```
The sequence \l_raw_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {a}
>  {b}
>  {c}.
```

How do I process each element "in place" with `\seq_map*` without having them
pushed to the input stream?

Naive tries:

- `\seq_set_from_clist:Nx \l_processed_seq {\seq_map_variable:NNn \l_raw_seq \i {,(\i)}}`: does not compile in consistence with the [doc](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/l3kernel/expl3.pdf): this `Nx` variant
  does not exist, and `\seq_map*` cannot be expanded this way into another
  "variable".
- `\Use{\Map{a,b,c}}` with a 2-stages processing: does not work as expected
  since `\Map{a,b,c}` remains unexpanded.

Is there anything I've missed about `expl3` logic there?
Is it possible to process my comma-separated input this way?
Are there alternatives or workarounds?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use two sequences; first apply the mapping to get the “adorned” items, then use them.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l__iagolito_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l__iagolito_out_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\MapAndUse}{ m }
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__iagolito_in_seq { #1 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l__iagolito_out_seq \l__iagolito_in_seq { (\exp_not:n { ##1 }) }
  \seq_use:Nn \l__iagolito_out_seq {~--~}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\MapAndUse{a,b,c}

\end{document}
```

An extended version where you can specify how to adorn the items and what to use between them:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l__iagolito_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l__iagolito_out_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\MapAndUse}{ mmm }
 {
  \cs_set_protected:Nn \__iagolito_mapanduse:n { #2 }
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__iagolito_in_seq { #1 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l__iagolito_out_seq \l__iagolito_in_seq
   {
    \__iagolito_mapanduse:n { \exp_not:n { ##1 } }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l__iagolito_out_seq { #3 }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\MapAndUse{a,b,c}{(#1)}{ -- }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, cheers :) I was missing `\seq_set_map` and `\exp_not`. It turns out the second one was actually the one I was trying to build :)

Comment: `\MapAndUse` does not work within `\caption` in a `figure` environment, what could be wrong? The compiler spits `! Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a. <to be read again> ` I can work around this bug using `\savebox`.

Comment: @iago-lito The generic `\MapAndUse` should be employed for defining semantic macros rather than explicitly. Do `\NewDocumentCommand{\parendash}{m}{\MapAndUse{#1}{(##1)}{ -- }}` and use `\parendash{a,b,c}`.

Comment: This is what I actually did but the error was spat by the very *semantic* macro. My mistake was to define the semantic macro with `\newcommand` instead of `\NewDocumentCommand`.. so your version does work :)

Comment: @iago-lito Always remember that the argument to `\caption` is a moving argument and that fragile commands need to be protected or made robust at the outset (which `\NewDocumentCommand` does).